# How to server jupyter-vue.js file from voila page?

Tags: voila, ipyvuetify

I am using Jupyter and voila to serve notebook as dashboard.
I am using ipyvuetify as the UI widget framework.
ipyvuetify fetches some static files such as jupyter-vue.js from the internet
This doesn't work with some of our users who have restricted Internet access.
How can I ensure the static files are served from the App Server itself.
Thanks

Comment: This might get more people in-the-know seeing it if you post it at [the Jupyter Community Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/)? If you do, please leave a pointer here and vice versa.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup. When your voila app starts, it at some point tries to locate the jupyter-vue.js component.
Serving from localhost:8866 the first related request of your app is

```
GET http://localhost:8866/voila/jupyter-vue.js
```

which is then redirected to

```
GET http://localhost:8866/voila/files/voila/jupyter-vue.js
```

At this point your app cannot find jupyter-vue.js locally and it falls back to CDN

```
GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jupyter-vue@^1.8.0/dist/index.js
```

This is the point where your users need a connection to the CDN. To work around,
you can download the js-components manually with a machine having internet connection.

```
$ curl https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jupyter-vue@^1.8.0/dist/index.js > jupyter-vue.js
```

you probably also want

```
$ curl https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jupyter-matplotlib@^0.11/dist/index.js > jupyter-matplotlib.js 
$ curl https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jupyter-vuetify@^1.8.4/dist/index.js > jupyter-vuetify.js
```

Put these file into a folder "voila" such that your notebook directory has the following setup

```
./notebooks/myapp.ipynb
./notebooks/voila/jupyter-vue.js
./notebooks/voila/jupyter-matplotlib.js
./notebooks/voila/jupyter-vuetify.js
```

Start your app

```
$ voila --VoilaConfiguration.file_whitelist=".*\.js" myapp.ipynb
```

Your app will now find the required components via the request

```
GET http://localhost:8866/voila/files/voila/jupyter-vue.js
```

Comment: The notebook setup must be ./notebooks/voila/jupyter-vuetify.js etc.